# Ajax pass id using POST with php (Error Undefined variable: id)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Im new In AJAx. My problem is I have ajax Function to pass variable ID in php when the page is load the error is  Undefined variable: id but when I look in firebug post id is past successfully . Here is my ajax.

```
$('.btn_edit').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
     var $this = $(this);
    var id_id = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(id_id);
         $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
         url: "edit_query.php",
             data:{id: id_id},
          success: function() {
        alert("Success Input");
```

and this is my php page to pass.

```
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $sql = mysql_query("select * from user where uid = ".$id."");
    $table = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql); 

    ?>
```

Comment: do you see your POST data in console...?

Comment: show the form as well..

Comment: Write : `success: function(data) { alert(data);}` ; and in php: `echo $id;`

Comment: remove `e.preventDefault();` from top and add it at the end

Comment: @Sudhir Yes I see it and the output is correct even I try to alert the sucessful data.

Comment: so about your answer to sudhir question in console you see the post ? so you see the id with correct value? if yes how you load your page that you wrote in your question ?

Comment: Actually the data is correct when it pass the value in ID the main problem is when i echo $_POST['id']; there is value output in firebug but in the page error is Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\administrator\edit_query.php on line 8.. How to Fixed this.?

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = mysql_query("select * from user where uid = ".$id."");
```

should be

```
$sql = mysql_query("select * from user where uid = $id ");
```

and

```
var id_id = $(this).attr('id');
alert(id_id);
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
     url: "edit_query.php",
     data:"id="+id_id,
     success: function() {
        alert("Success Input");
     }
```

Comment: I think your Example is all same.

Comment: send your data as `data:"id="+id_id`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$.post( "edit_query.php", { id: id_id })
  .done(function( data ) {
    alert( data );
  });
```

Comment: I try this I running but I try to echo $_POST['id'] there is value but in console it is empty. How can it be empty whilw when u echo it there is value. error is Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\administrator\edit_query.php on line 8

Comment: @AmitSoni actually the edit_query.php is the the code which is this

Comment: $id = $_POST['id'];
    $sql = mysql_query("select * from user where uid = ".$id."");
    $table = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);

Comment: only this $id = $_POST['id'];

Comment: try `print_r($_POST);` and see what you are getting

Comment: Array([id] => 12345)   this is the output. the 12345 is example id in my database..

Comment: one last try `$_GET["id"]`

Comment: same :( I try using foreach

Comment: `$.post( "edit_query.php", { 'id': id_id })
  .done(function( data ) {
    alert( data );
  });` make sure you have single quotes around your data i.e. `'id':id_id` and grab data as `$id = $_POST['id']`

Answer (score 0):

try this

#### edit_query.php

```
<?php
$id = $_POST['id'];
$sql = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM user WHERE uid = '.$id);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc();
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($row);
exit;
```

#### your.js

```
$(function(){
  var onClick, successHandler;
  onClick = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post('edit_query.php',{id:$(this).attr('id')},successHandler,'json');
  };
  successHandler = function (json) {alert(json.uid);};
  $('.btn_edit').click(onClick);
});
```